# Exception Handling and Logging Application blocks Enterprise Library 5.0

Tags: configuration, console, enterprise-library

Friends

I want to do some Hands on Enterprise Library 5.0 Exception Handling and Logging Blocks.I am new to it. I would appreciate if you guys could provide me some links to Configuration Console and how to use these blocks.

Thanks
Vivek

Answer (score 0):

The configuration tool is part of the download of Enterprise Library so if you have Enterprise Library you should have it.

Probably your best bet would be to look at the [Developer's Guide on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953181%28PandP.50%29.aspx).  There are sections on [Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953185%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) and [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff953192%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx).

Or if you just wanted to dive right in you can download the [Hands-On Labs for Microsoft Enterprise Library 5.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=6932) and work through those.